# Alter MySQL table varchar fields to decimal fields

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL-table with several colomns like

```
id  text_1  val_1   text_2  text_3  val_2
1   'bla'   1,23    'blub'  5,67    12,34
```

Unfortunately all fields are defined as `varchar`. Now I try to alter the table to make some fields decimal values.

I would try

```
UPDATE table SET
val_1 = CAST(val_1 AS DECIMAL(5,2)),
val_2 = CAST(val_2 AS DECIMAL(5,2));
```

This should give me decimal values with two decimals and a max value of 999,99, correct?

And is this the correct way to alter the table structure? This should be a one time conversion, as values should get da decimal type and strings should be varchar type.

Do I have to convert the 'comma' to 'point' first?

**Update**

Unfortunately I have also values like `<0,01'. But the field should be a decimal field. What can I do with that?

Comment: No. And besides that you need to change the data types you should also change your complete table structure. What does the table contain. We might be able to help you making a better table design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to convert the , to a . first.

```
UPDATE sometable SET val_1=REPLACE(val_1,',','.');
```

After that the table has to be altered:

```
ALTER TABLE sometable MODIFY COLUMN val_1 DECIMAL(5,2);
```

Your update statement is not required.

If you have smaller values, they will get rounded (down in your case). To prevent rounding, use another `DECIMAL` setup (with more digits).

Comment: Thank you for that. How should I do the update? Do you have an idea for the problem which I described in the updated post?