# How to convert a column from varchar to decimal in MySQL, knowing that the values are separated with commas

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

I tried the following MySQL requests to convert a column from varchar to decimal type, but I got Errors.

```
ALTER TABLE `cmd-services` CHANGE `Qte Sortie` `Qte Sortie` CAST(REPLACE(`Qte Sortie`, ',', '.') as DECIMAL(20,2));

ALTER TABLE `cmd-services` MODIFY `Qte Sortie` CAST(REPLACE(`Qte Sortie`, ',', '.') as DECIMAL(20,2));
```

I need your help. 
thank's.

Comment: Replace the values in one query then update the data type separately. Back up first of course.

Comment: This question is a duplicate and has already been answered. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056035/alter-mysql-table-varchar-fields-to-decimal-fields

Comment: Thank you. 
In the question that you mentioned they use Replace(), and I use CAST().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps

1. Update the column and set all non numberic values to null so alter
   won't fail.
2. Alter the table and set the type to int

Step 1:

```
UPDATE `cmd-services`
set `Qte Sortie` = CAST(REPLACE(`Qte Sortie`, ',', '.') as DECIMAL(20,2));
```

Step 2:

```
ALTER TABLE `cmd-services`
MODIFY `Qte Sortie` DECIMAL(20,2);
```

> This takes the assumption that the columns allow nulls. If not then
>   that needs to be handled as well.
>
> For example: By altering the column to allow null, then after it has
>   been converted to DECIMAL then set all null values to 0 and alter the
>   table to not allow null.

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thank you!